# IIS Cache-Control and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, iis

We have a website that uses AngularJS. We have our main index.html and then all of the other pages get loaded using angular's 'ng-view' and '$routProvider' inside of our index.html.

As an example, let's say our IIS Cache-control Max-age is set to 5 minutes (I know this is a bad idea but helps with the point). When the 5 minutes have expired and they click on a link that takes them to a new page using the ng-view, does the browser also check index.html against the IIS cache-control and grab a fresh copy of it or does it only check our index.html if they reload / refresh the page after 5 minutes?

From my understanding, the 'child' pages (if you will) that get loaded using ng-view will be checked against the IIS cache-control header but I can't find anything about the 'parent' page (our index.html) that loads the 'child' pages. Does it get reloaded with the 'child' pages loaded inside of the ng-view?

Comment: Are you using HTML5 mode with url re-writing? Or legacy mode without url re-writing?

Comment: legacy without url re-writing. Is the answer different depending on if you use URL rewrite or not?